# Can't send mail over php

Tags: php

I have a form where an user enters into a message, and the message gets sent to the recipient on the other end. I have tried this script multiple times, scoured tutorials, yet I can't seem to find what's wrong. Any ideas?

HTML Form:

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
       <?php 
        if(isset($sent))
                 echo 'Your message has been sent. '; ?>
      <label for="Name">Name</label><br />                  
      <input type="text" class="textbox" size="35" id="Name" name="Name" <?php if(isset($name)) echo "value=\"$name\"";?> /><br />
      <label for="Service">Service</label><br />
      <input type="text" size="35" class="textbox" id="Service" name="Service" <?php  if(isset($subject)) echo"value=\"$subject\"";?> /><br />
      <label for="Email">Email</label><br />
      <input type="text" size="35" class="textbox" id="Email" name="Email" <?php if(isset($from)) echo"value=\"$from\""; ?> /><br />     
      <label for="message">Message</label><br />
      <textarea rows="95" cols="100" id="message" name="message"><?php if(isset($message)) echo"$message"; ?></textarea><br />
      <button type="submit">Send Message</button>               
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['Name']) && isset($_POST['Email']) && isset($_POST['Service']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $from = $_POST['Email'];
    $subject = $_POST['Service'];
    $to = "emailtestertora@gmail.com";
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Contact`(`Name`, `Email`, `Message`, `Service`) VALUES('$name', '$from', '$message', '$subject')");
    $headers = "From:".$from;
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
        $msgsent = true;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Have you checked mail() is working or not?Var_dump($msgsent) to check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Do you have a mail server setup?

Comment: @Dr.Dan, yeah I've tried debugging and I've confirmed that the script doesn't send because I get all the information I sent out right back into the form

Comment: @aspirin, how do i set up a mail server?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429605/how-to-send-mail-through-localhost

Comment: I'm using an online web host, not my own server so I won't be able to set up my own?

Comment: Oh..I thought you were using locahost. In that case you shouldn't need to setup one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Apologies as this should go as a comment, but it'll be easier layed out in the textbox)

Firstly, debug with the following code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

if (mail('emailtestertora@gmail.com', 'test', 'test')) {
    echo 'Mail Sent';
} else {
    echo 'Mail Failed';
}

?>
```

This script will give you an error message when sending the e-mail that will help you debug.

---

BUT, the important part of this comment, is that the e-mail script above is open to spam (as well as SQL injection). I would **strongly encourage** you to use a one of the functions/classes that are available that will help you cut out the security holes holes in your mail script.

If you are determined to roll-your-own then great, but please read up about e-mail spam header injection before letting this script on a server. Spammers can send thousands of e-mails very quickly when they find an open script like this, they regularly test automatically so you must clamp down.

(And read up about PHP Database object - PDO - at the same time to save the MySQL injection.)

Comment: I think I'm going to go with creating my own just as an challenge. I'll look into those two, thanks! :D So I tried debugging, but all I get is the message saying "mail sent", but I receive no message.

Comment: In which case, the mail program on your server (commonly sendmail for linux) accepted the e-mail. You need to debug why that's not sending mails - go to the lowest level ("mail") and send a message from there; turn on logging to check that e-mails are being sent; checking receiving server (if you have one you can control) to see if/why it might be rejected etc. The PHP bit looks fine - so I think you'll need the server forum to help you with the next bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your service provider may block your mail.
2. If you are in dedicated server you may need to configure a mail server

Thanks

Sreeraj

Answer (score 0):

Use this method
this is a `php` email script which dose not need any `smpt` connection

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```